# Run a shell command from a variable in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to run a command from a variable in shell script. The shell being used is bash shell.

The file `exp` contains:

```
abcdef
```

Executing the following command:

```
sed s/b/\ / exp
```

...produces the output:

```
a  cdef
```

But executing:

```
cmd="sed s/b/\ / exp"
echo $cmd
$cmd
```

...produces the following error:

```
sed s/b/\ / exp
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command
```

I can see that adding `eval` in front of the execution works. But I cannot understand why. Can you explain *why* one method is working and the other is not working?

Comment: Don't put commands into strings. As you have seen, it doesn't always work. Here is some [recommended reading](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to put all command arguments in one variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542911/how-to-put-all-command-arguments-in-one-variable)

Comment: @tripleee note the problem ended up being with the interpretation of `sed` itself. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

The problem you are having is that the space itself is not being interpreted properly by Bash.

See how it works well if you replace the `b` with another character, say `X`:

```
$ cmd="sed s/b/X/ exp"
$ $cmd
aXcdef
```

So the workaround is to use the hexadecimal for the space, which is `20`:

```
$ cmd="sed s/b/\x20/ exp"
$ $cmd
a cdef
```

Or to use [`eval`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23111/40596) to execute the command itself:

```
$ cmd="sed s/b/\ / exp"
$ eval "$cmd"
a cdef
```

---

As Tom Fenech suggested, storing commands in variables in not a good approach, as described in [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). It can work sometimes but in other cases can produce unpredictable results. An alternative is to consider using a function.

Finally, note `eval` can come handy in cases like this, only that being very careful on what is stored. Some good reading: [Variable as command; eval vs bash -c](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124594/40596).

Comment: Well.. he did say "bash", but as a rule, I would not start by introducing to a beginner a bash extension (the \x20), without noting that it isn't POSIX.  Rather, the types of escaping and reasons for these would be the usual place to start.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a quoting issue:

`cmd="sed s/b/\ / exp"` makes `$cmd` hold a sequence of characters with no special meaning. So your `\` does not escape your space.

`eval` treats that sequence of characters as a command, and re-assign the special meaning to your `\`.

See also: [Preserving quotes in bash function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3260920/110488)

Answer (score 1):

If you need the output in the variable then use,

```
cmd=$(sed 's/b/ /' exp)
```

Like @thomas says, If you are using the variable you can use the double quotes.

Comment: This is just the same as I posted.

Comment: Its the same as my post,

Comment: So what? Before posting your answer I started to type the answer!

Comment: This answer does not address the original question, which was about storing the command itself (not its output) in a variable and then doing something with the variable to run the command.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
cmd=$(sed "s/b/\ /" exp)
```

To store data in variable use `var=$(commands)`

Comment: If you are posting the answer to the question means then no one  other should not post ah?

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S Off course everyone can post what they like, but posting 100% same as other are not needed.

Comment: This answer does not address the original question, which was about storing the command itself (not its output) in a variable and then doing something with the variable to run the command.

Answer (score 0):

If you quote the sed parameters, the script is easier to read, and backslashes are needed only to escape special characters (such as backslash and the double-quotes):

```
cmd=$(sed "s/b/ /" exp)
```

If you use single-quotes, that reduces the need for escaping more -- but prevents you from using variables such as this:

```
xxx=something
cmd=$(sed "s/b/$xxx/" exp)
```

Comment: This is just the same as I posted

Comment: we were editing at the same time - so I pointed out some additional features which you have not (yet) added to your answer.

Comment: @Jotne you all posted a similar question within seconds. And this one at least has some explanation. I don't think it is quite fair to downvote them just for this.

Comment: It seems that he downvoted while I was expanding my explanation - it's okay now.

Comment: It seems like everyone is suggesting alternative answers. Please explain why the method is not working.

Comment: This answer does not address the original question, which was about storing the command itself (not its output) in a variable and then doing something with the variable to run the command.

Comment: Actually, the question was not how to use eval, but *why* one method works and the other does not.